# html table find row before last using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a standard HTML table.

Using jquery how do I find the row before the last row of the table ?

`$('#table tr:last')` will give me the last row, but how do I access the row that comes right before the last ?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$('#table tr').eq(-2)
```

or

```
$('#table tr:last').prev()
```

or

```
$('#table tr').eq($('#table tr').length - 2)
```

[**Demo for the three solutions.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/5hnGz/2/)

Comment: I think using $('#table tr').eq(-2); would be better/faster (Negative use of eq() starts from set's end and will save you the construction of another jQuery element).

Comment: @JoshLeaves - I did not know you could do that! I've thrown it in, updating the demo too! Thanks for that most useful bit of knowledge, and `<facepalm>` for not having known that :(

Comment: Discovered this by mistake when using unchecked parameters/args =) Pretty useful, I wish arrays in C would behave the same way :D